# Jumpserver/Bastion host for SSH connections

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, ssh

I'm looking for a rather simple implementation/software to control ssh access to multiple servers.

I've tried software like [Teleport](https://gravitational.com/teleport/) but it's way over-engineered for my requirements, and I find the documentation really unclear to set it up as "simple" jump host.

I'm aware that configuring any linux server as jump host is possible by creating a user that has access to `server.com`, but the usermanagement part in this scenario is anything but friendly.

---

In the very basic, what 'm looking for comes down to this:

- Client connects to server.com via proxy: jumpserver.com
- jumpserver.com checks the user that is connecting if it's allowed to connect to server.com.
- When jumpserver.com determines that this user is allowed to connect to server.com it passes the connection to server.com.

In this flow server.com should reject all incoming connections unless it's from jumpserver.com

I drew a flowchart which hopefully explains it a bit using visuals:

### [image]

Preferable the jumpserver has some sort of webui so managing these users should be an easy task.